# creating a python pandas dataframe from a list of dictionaries when one entry of each dictionary is itself an array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a dataframe from a list of dictionaries. However, one entry of this list is itself an array (or could be a pandas.Series). I need to do grouping and averaging and I could not get it to work.
Suppose I had

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
ls=[{'A': 1,'B':4, 'n':.5, 's':.9},{'A': 2,'B':4, 'n':.55, 's':.95},
    {'A': 1,'B':5, 'n':.52, 's':.92},{'A': 2,'B':5, 'n':.57, 's':.97}]
df=pd.DataFrame(ls)
```

I can perform averages of the numbers values n and s by performing (supposing A is the quantity I'm interested in and B represents a variable to average over, like a seed)

```
g=df.groupby('A')
g['n'].mean()
```

However, if my dictionary is given by

```
ls2=[{'A': 1,'B':4, 'n':np.random.random(3), 's':np.random.random(3)},
    {'A': 2,'B':4, 'n':np.random.random(3), 's':np.random.random(3)},
    {'A': 1,'B':5, 'n':np.random.random(3), 's':np.random.random(3)},
    {'A': 2,'B':5, 'n':np.random.random(3), 's':np.random.random(3)}]
df2=pd.DataFrame(ls2)
```

the above approach does not work. Here n and s would e.g. be given for three different points in time (these are measured quantities). I would like to create a dataframe such that I can write something like

```
g2=df2.groupby('A')
g['n'][1].mean()
```

to get the mean for the second component of n, split into different values of the variable A. I also looked into using pd.panel for this, but that also did not seem suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are on the right track, but you didn't construct the dataframe correctly. Notice how the `Dataframe` is constructed in line 24 and 25 here:

```
In [24]:

df3=map(pd.DataFrame, ls2)
In [25]:

print df3
[   A  B         n         s
0  1  4  0.029207  0.232231
1  1  4  0.190384  0.173439
2  1  4  0.911990  0.190540

[3 rows x 4 columns],    A  B         n         s
0  2  4  0.197783  0.607027
1  2  4  0.294718  0.899167
2  2  4  0.503692  0.887258

[3 rows x 4 columns],    A  B         n         s
0  1  5  0.536258  0.406545
1  1  5  0.351419  0.197343
2  1  5  0.572489  0.436308

[3 rows x 4 columns],    A  B         n         s
0  2  5  0.607138  0.535803
1  2  5  0.086167  0.336044
2  2  5  0.650546  0.886143

[3 rows x 4 columns]]
In [26]:

df3=df3[0].append(df3[1:])
In [27]:

print df3.groupby('A').mean()
     B         n         s
A                         
1  4.5  0.431958  0.272734
2  4.5  0.390007  0.691907

[2 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not quite answer my question (apologies for not being clear enough). This now averages over all the entries of 'n' for e.g. A=1. (for A=1 I get mean=(.029+.190+.912+.536+.351+.572)/6=.431 ). However I want to be able to access the mean of, say, just the second entry of n. So I would like to calculate mean=(.19+.35)/2=0.27 for A=1.

Comment: Oh, I (kind-of) see. In this case you want to have 3 values for A=1, right? `df3.groupby(['A', df3.index]).mean()`. Do you mean a result like that? Works as long as each `np.array` is of the same length.

Comment: I also figured out that making a new column via `df3['time']=df3.index` and `g=df3.groupby(['A','time'])['n']` and `g.mean()` also works. So yes, this answers my question. Thanks!